# How to get the current selection in a TCustomFileDialog?

Tags: delphi

I've got a `TFileOpenDialog` with an `OnSelectionChange` event hooked up, trying to take certain actions based on the selection.  It fires every time the selected item in the shell view box is changed, but the `FileName` property seems to always contain the name of the most recently selected file.

If you select a **folder** the `FileName` property does not get updated. I understand that this is because a folder is not a file.

So clearly `FileName` is the wrong thing to read. Obviously there's something in there that knows what's currently *actually selected.*  How do I get at that?

Comment: The `FileName` property is updated with the *current* selected file whenever the selection changes for any reason. So what is the *actual* problem? Please provide an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: As I wrote in the question, the actual problem is that it is updated with the current selected **file**, but if you select a **folder**, the `FileName` property is not updated.  This is relevant to what I'm working on.

Comment: I can repro the issue. But I think it behaves as designed.

Comment: `TFileOpenDialog` is for opening **files** (hense the name), so of course it is not going to report a selected **folder**. Why would you expect it to? If you want to select a folder, you have to use `SelectDirectory()` instead (or `SHBrowseForFolder()` directly).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: 1) have a look at element #4 under the Options property.  2) because I'm using `IFileDialogCustomize` to display metadata about the currently selected file, and if what is currently selected is not a valid file (because it's a folder, for example) then the display needs to be cleared.

Comment: In the `OnSelectionChange` event, you can use [`TFileOpenDialog.ShellItem.GetAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761138.aspx) to find out what type of item is currently selected.  Keep in mind that `TFileOpenDialog` can display more then just filesystem items, and `IShellItem` can represent non-filesystem items, but the `FileName` property only support filesystem items.

Answer (score 3):

```
procedure TMyForm.DialogBoxSelectionChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  HRes: HRESULT;
  Attr: DWORD;
begin
  if DialogBox.ShellItem <> nil then
  begin
    HRes := DialogBox.ShellItem.GetAttributes(SFGAO_FILESYSTEM or SFGAO_FOLDER, Attr);
    if Succeeded(HRes) then
    begin
      if (Attr and SFGAO_FOLDER) = 0 then
      begin
        // must be a file, display info as needed
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  // clear info as needed...
end;
```

Comment: I tried this, but `ShellItem` appears to return `nil` no matter what I click on.

Comment: I tested it, `TFileOpenDialog.ShellItem` is not nil when selecting files and folders. The `ShellItem` is where the `FileName` property gets its value from, so it cannot be nil.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

```
var
  item: IShellItem;
  filename: PChar;
begin
  DialogBox.Dialog.GetCurrentSelection(item);
  if item = nil then
  begin
    //nothing is selected; handle appropriately
  end
  else begin
    item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, filename);
    //handle appropriately
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TFileOpenDialog` has `ShellItem` and `ShellItems` properties, you do not need to access `GetCurrentSelection()` directly. It calls that internally before triggering the `OnSelectionChange` event. But yes, you do need to resort to `IShellItem(s)` directly in order to know what is physically selected in the dialog.

Comment: @Mason: This code you showed is essentially the same code that `TFileOpenDialog` uses internally to populate the `FileName` property before triggering the `OnSelectionChange` event. It returns the last selected file, even when selecting a folder. You have to query `DialogBox.ShellItem` to find out if a file or folder is selected, like `TLama`'s link shows (you can do it in the event, you don't have to derive an interceptor).

Comment: @Remy, ah, that's right. [`Fixed`](http://pastebin.com/tMP6rrBX). Still for non-multiselection.